# JUnit 5 Parameterized Test - 'Cannot invoke non-static method' in @MethodSource with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-testing, junit5

## Expect

Convert a standard JUnit 5 test into a parameterized test in order to iterate through a stream of test cases using the `@ParamterizedTest` and `@MethodSource` annotations in Kotlin.

## Observe

The `@MethodSource` is unable to access the stream of data. This seems to be an issue with this annotation specifically, as `@ValueSource(strings = ["SF", "NYC"])` iterates through the statically defined options as expected.

Error:

> PreconditionViolationException: Cannot invoke non-static method {someMethodName} on a null target.

## Implement

The parameterized test is set to pass in a stream of data classes similar to the setup outlined by Phillip Hauer in [Data Classes for Parameterized Tests](https://phauer.com/2018/best-practices-unit-testing-kotlin/#data-classes-for-parameterized-tests).

### Code

*build.gradle (:SomeProject)*

```
dependencies {
    ...    
    classpath("de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:$junit5_version")
}
```

*build.gradle (:someModule)*

```
apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"
android {
    ...
    compileOptions.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2"
}
```

*SomeTest.kt*

```
class SomeTest {
    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    private fun someDataStates() = Stream.of(
        // Kotlin data class
        TestState("123"),
        TestState("345")
    )

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("someDataStates")
    fun someTest(testState: TestState) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Test state here.
        ...
    }
}
```

### Build environment

- Android Studio 4.0
- Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
- Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS 10.15.5
- GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
- Memory: 1979M
- Cores: 16
- Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
- Non-Bundled Plugins: cn.wjdghd.unique.plugin.id, com.android.tool.sizereduction.plugin, com.developerphil.adbidea, com.thoughtworks.gauge, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore

## Attempted solutions

### 1. Refactor test case data states to a top-level function.

*TestCases.kt*

```kotlin
fun someDataStates() = Stream.of(
    TestState("123"),
    TestState("345")
)
```

*SomeTest.kt*

```kotlin
private fun SomeDataStates() = someDataStates()

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("SomeDataStates")
fun someTest(testState: TestState) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
   // Test state here.
   ...

}
```

### 2. Refactor test case data states to a top-level function of type `List` instead of `Stream`.

```kotlin
fun someDataStates() = listOf(
    TestState("123"),
    TestState("345")
)
```

## Full error log

> org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot invoke non-static method [private final {someMethodName} on a null target.
>
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:296)
>      at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:682)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.lambda$provideArguments$1(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:46)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:272)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:272)
>       at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:106)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:41)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
>       at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
>       Suppressed: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
>           at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:281)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$6(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:90)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.close(AbstractPipeline.java:323)
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:279)
>           ... 49 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: Wow. I think I never saw such a well-structured question. 

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I guess you're missing the information, to tell JUnit to instantiate your test class once, like this:

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS

@TestInstance(PER_CLASS) // <--- This one will do the trick
class SomeTest {

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("someDataStates")
    fun someTest(testState: TestState) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Test state here.
        ...
    }

    private fun someDataStates() = listOf(
        TestState("123"),
        TestState("345")
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that `Lifecycle.PER_CLASS`is defined in past projects under _app/src/test/resources_ in Android Studio. 

File name: _junit-platform.properties_.

Code: `junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default=per_class`.

_See: [2.10.1 Changing the Default Test Instance Lifecycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle-changing-default)_

Answer (score 6):

Using `@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)`, you might have trouble for instance when trying to verify a function has been called X times with `mockito` or `mockk`. You'll have to sum all your calls.

In this case, use `@JvmStatic` :

```
class SomeTest {

    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        private fun someDataStates() = listOf(
            TestState("123"),
            TestState("345")
        )
    }
    
    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("someDataStates")
    fun someTest(testState: TestState) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Test state here.
        ...
    }
}
```

*Edit 27/08/2021:* since latest version of kotlin (tested with 1.5.21), don't set the @JvmStatic method as `private` or it'll end again in a `PreconditionViolationException`

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you can't use the `@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)` annotation, you can use the `@TestFactory` annotation instead of the `@ParameterizedTest` annotation on your test method.

```java
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicTest> someTest() {
    return someDataStates().map(testState -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest(testState.getName(), () -> someTest0(testState)));
}

private void someTest0(TestState testState) {
    // Test state here.
}

private Stream<TestState> someDataStates() {
    return Stream.of(
            new TestState("123"),
            new TestState("345")
    );
}
```